# Logic behind URLs in JAVA

Tags: java, url

I am struggling to understand an existing piece of code, that is as follows.
I can't change this piece of code and need to place this WordNet folder accordingly. 
I don't know where to place it in my Java project.

`URL url = new URL("file:WordNet-JWI/3.0/dict");`

Comment: You are using what ? Eclipse ?

Comment: Yes, I am using Eclipse :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create a `File` object and print out the path of it.

```
URL url = new URL("file:WordNet-JWI/3.0/dict");
File f = new File(url.getFile());
System.out.println(f.getCanonicalPath());
```